# Asp.net update a partial view and download a file

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a website with a list of downloads and a list with the history of the already downloaded files.
When I click on one I want to that the download of the selected file starts and the new item is added to the history.
The download works so far:

```
    public async Task<ActionResult> DownloadSelection(int selectionId, DownloadFormat format)
    {
        var selection = databaseSelectionService.GetById(selectionId);

        string fileName = selection.Name + FileNamingHelper.GetFileExtensionByFormat(format);
        var fileBytes = await downloadManager.ExecuteSelection(selection, applicationUserManager.FindById(User.Identity.GetUserId()), format);
        return File(fileBytes, MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet, fileName);
    }
```

And I call it via an HTML.ActionLink:

```
@Html.ActionLink(Strings.ExcelLabel, "DownloadSelection", "Home", new { selectionId = selection.Id, format = DownloadFormat.Excel }, null)
```

Now my issue is, that to refresh the history, I would have to return a partial view. But since I already return a File as ActionResult I can't return a partial View aswell.

I tried an approach to use an Ajax.ActionLink and add an AjaxOption for OnSuccess to call a second controller once the download was successful who would return the partial view. But somehow my javascript function was never called.

```
@section scripts
{
    function testFunction()
    {
        alert("huhu");
    }
}

@Ajax.ActionLink(Strings.CsvLabel, "DownloadSelection", "Home", new { selectionId = selection.Id, format = DownloadFormat.CSV }, new AjaxOptions{OnSuccess = "testFunction" })
```

What would be a good approach to solve this?

View:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = Strings.SelectionsTitle;
}

<h2>@ViewBag.Title</h2>

@if (Model.AssignedDatabaseSelections.Any())
{
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Abfrage</th>
            <th style="text-align:right">Download</th>
        </tr>
        @foreach (var selection in Model.AssignedDatabaseSelections)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@selection.DisplayName</td>
                <td style="text-align:right">
                   @Ajax.ActionLink(Strings.CsvLabel, "DownloadSelection", "Home", new { selectionId = selection.Id, format = DownloadFormat.CSV }, new AjaxOptions{OnSuccess = "testFunction" })  |
                   @Ajax.ActionLink(Strings.ExcelLabel, "DownloadSelection", "Home", new { selectionId = selection.Id, format = DownloadFormat.Excel}, new AjaxOptions{OnSuccess = "testFunction" })
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </table>
}
else
{
    <div>
        @Strings.NoSelectionsPlaceholder
    </div>
}

<h2>@Strings.DownloadHistoryTitle</h2>

@if (Model.DownloadRecords.Any())
{
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Abfrage</th>
            <th>Zeitraum von</th>
            <th>Zeitraum bis</th>
            <th style="text-align:right">Download</th>
        </tr>
        @foreach (var downloadRecord in Model.DownloadRecords)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@downloadRecord.Selection.DisplayName</td>
                <td>@downloadRecord.TimeRangeStart.ToString("d")</td>
                <td>@downloadRecord.TimeRangeEnd.ToString("d")</td>
                <td style="text-align:right">
                    @Html.ActionLink(Strings.CsvLabel, "RedownloadRecord", "Home", new {recordId = downloadRecord.Id, format = DownloadFormat.CSV}, null)
                    |
                    @Html.ActionLink(Strings.ExcelLabel, "RedownloadRecord", "Home", new {recordId = downloadRecord.Id, format = DownloadFormat.Excel}, null)
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </table>
}
else
{
    <div>
        @Strings.NoDownloadsPlaceholder
    </div>
}
```

EDIT: added the Whole View Code

Comment: You can just make an ajax call to return the partial (although all you shold really need is to return a `JsonResult` and update the DOM using jQuery if both the list of downloads and the list of history are in the same view)), and then in the success callback, make a redirect to download the file (`location.href = "...";`

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Do you have an example where I can see that? Actually I'm quite new and can't really imagen how I could do that..

Comment: Bit hard to give you further help without seeing the view

Comment: Sorry for my late answer. I added the whole view with the code I tried to execute a javascript function onSuccess after the download.

Comment: So just to be clear - if you click on one of the links in the first section (for `AssignedDatabaseSelections`), you would want to update the record in the database with that `selection.Id` (e.g. to flag it as having been downloaded), and so that it future it would be rendered in the `DownloadRecords` section? If that is the case, please confirm and I can add an answer.

Comment: yes, that's exactly what I try to do :)

Comment: OK, No time just now, but will add an answer in about 60 min

Comment: that would be awesome!

Comment: Just realized your 2nd table has a 2 extra columns for `TimeRangeStart` and `TimeRangeEnd` which need to be added when moving the row from one table to the other. What are they?  And can they be calculated in the client, or can they be calculated and returned in the method that updates the downloaded flag in the DB?

Comment: That is the timerange of the data who is contained in the downloaded file. So ideally there would be a way to just load the Model.DownloadRecords again with the new entry. The original entry in the AssignedDatabaseSelections stays there. when you download the file it generates a new download record in the database for that selection.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165955/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-npadrutt).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot return a file for download via an ajax call, so using `@Ajax.ActionLink()` is not suitable. Instead, handle the click of your links in the first table to make and ajax call that updates the record in the database (i.e. to indicate its been downloaded), and in the success callback, update the 2nd table, and use `location.href` to download the file. Add an `id` attribute to distinguish the tables

```
<table id="assigned">
    <thead> ... add table headings ... </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var selection in Model.AssignedDatabaseSelections)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@selection.DisplayName</td>
                <td>
                    @Html.ActionLink(Strings.CsvLabel, "DownloadSelection", "Home", new { selectionId = selection.Id, format = DownloadFormat.CSV }, null)
                    ....
                </td>
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>
<div id="history">
    <table>
        <thead> ... add table headings ... </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach (var downloadRecord in Model.DownloadRecords)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>@downloadRecord.Selection.DisplayName</td>
                    ....
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

And add a script to handle the click event of links in the first table, make an ajax call to update the record in the database, and in its success callback, update the 2nd table, and finally download the file.

```
$('#assigned').on('click', 'a', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // cancel default redirect
    var downloadUrl = $(this).attr('href');
    var id = $(this).data('id');
    var row = $(this).closest('tr');
    var url = '@Url.Action("UpdateHistory")';
    $.post(url, { id: id }, function(response){
        $('#history').html(response); // update the table
        location.href = downloadUrl; // download file
    });
});
```

Where the `UpdateHistory` method is

```
[HttpPost]
public PartialViewResult UpdateHistory(int id)
{
    // Update the database record to set the flag its been downloaded
    var model = ... // Generate a collection of the records used to display in the History table
    return PartialView("_History", model);
}
```

And `_History.cshtml` is a partial view that generates the 2nd table in your main view.